# Could a Dyson Sphere-like object be made to encase a black hole without collapsing?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, material-science, estimation

In this question, I'm not asking about the feasibility of building a black hole Dyson Sphere or the effectiveness, I simply want to know if an object could stay in a locked position encasing a black hole without collapsing in on itself. It doesn't matter if it would collapse before in place, I just care about the final position and if so, what shape would be best suited for this?

Comment: Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope estimation?

Answer (score 7):

> … if an object could stay in a locked position encasing a black hole without collapsing in on itself.

**Yes.**

Solutions for a thin static spherical shells around a nonrotaing black hole have been considered in the following paper:

- Frauendiener, J., Hoenselaers, C., & Konrad, W. (1990). *A shell around a black hole*, Classical and Quantum Gravity, 7(4), 585, [doi:10.1088/0264-9381/7/4/011](https://doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/7/4/011), [free pdf](https://homepages.uni-tuebingen.de//wilfried.konrad/seiten/shell_around.pdf).

The authors found that for a reasonable constraints on the equation of state for the shell material it is possible to have a shell around the black hole, even possibly inside the radius of [circular photon orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere), but necessarily bounded away from the horizon.

Another paper of note:

- Brady, P. R., Louko, J., & Poisson, E. (1991). *Stability of a shell around a black hole*. Physical Review D, 44(6), 1891, [doi:10.1103/PhysRevD.44.1891](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.44.1891).

These authors have considered *mechanical stability* of such a shell and found that …

> … the shell is stable against radial perturbations only outside a critical radius which is always larger than the radius of the circular photon orbit. The surface energy density of a stable shell is always larger than twice the surface pressure, and thus satisfies the dominant energy condition by a wide margin.

So, a *mechanicaly stable* Dyson sphere must be located some distance away from circular photon orbit, but it is conceivable that some active control system could stabilize Dyson spheres even inside this radius.