# Can a stable structure actually enclose a black hole of a certain radius?

Tags: gravity, black-holes

If a structure were sufficiently strong at a large enough radius from a black hole, could it completely enclose a black hole without collapsing in, since in some sense the material would pull on itself uniformly?

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/537440

Answer (score 3):

The structure you are describing sounds similar to a [Dyson sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere), which has been proposed as a method of extracting energy from a star by an extremely advanced civilisation. For distances much larger than the Schwarzschild radius, a black hole has the same gravitational field as a star of the same mass, so the same physics applies*. It is theoretically possible, but well beyond the realms of current materials science and engineering.

One problem with constructing such a structure is that it is unstable: small perturbations would cause it to drift off until the central mass collided with the wall. This is precisely because of the effect you mention: the gravitational forces cancel out leaving no net force on the shell (this is known as the [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem)).

*Thanks to D. Halsey for suggesting this clarification.

Comment: The question asks about a structure surrounding a black hole, but your answer only discusses a structure around a star. I think your answer would be improved by noting that there could be essentially no difference in the two cases. The OP doesn't seem to realize that.

Comment: @D.Halsey thanks, I've added a clarifying sentence.