# How to correct the Schwarzschild metric in the presence of Dyson sphere?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, stars, neutron-stars

I was solving a problem in general relativity about Dyson sphere around a star. I don't have any problem solving the problem but in the question Dyson sphere was assumed to be massless. I checked [Dyson sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere):

> Also if assuming a radius of $1 AU$, there may not be sufficient building material in the Solar System to construct a Dyson shell. Anders Sandberg estimates that there is $1.82×10^{26}$ kg of easily usable building material in the Solar System, enough for a 1 AU shell with a mass of $600 kg/m^2$—about $8–20 cm$ thick on average, depending on the density of the material. This includes the hard-to-access cores of the gas giants; the inner planets alone provide only $11.79×10^{24} kg$, enough for a $1 AU$ shell with a mass of just $42 kg/m^2$.[14]

apparently it has some mass. I assume this comes from the fact that this enormous megastructure will change the Schwarzschild metric and the question does not ask us to go into depth.

I was wondering how to correct the Schwarzschild metric in the presence of massfull Dyson sphere.

Comment: Not an answer, just a way to approach it:  There's a standard technique due to Israel to "patch together" two metrics and view the joining surface as a thin shell of stress-energy.   I suspect, given the results of Birkhoff's theorem, that the resulting metric will therefore be an "interior" Schwarzschild solution and an "exterior" Schwarzschild solution patched together in this way.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you please share the link to the related papers?

Comment: There is also another issue: realistic Dyson spheres are essentially dust in orbit around the star (mass and some negligible momentum), but the less realistic Dyson shells will have internal pressure. Solving the field through patching remains the same, but there are some fun papers showing that there is a minimal radius Dyson sphere (way beyond what normal matter can handle) where the energy conditions start to break.

Comment: I think anyone interested in a Dyson Sphere would expect it to appear as as a static non-orbiting shell, or a rigid rotating structure.  I don't believe a dust layer can orbit as a whole (non-equatorial orbits!) nor stay stationary.

Comment: Have a look at the links from [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/537521/) to a related question.

Comment: @m4r35n357 - I was using dust in the standard relativity sense. If you assume a pressure-less, collision-less system of particles it is trivial to give it zero angular momentum yet orbit by placing two particles in the same orbit with opposite velocities. For a real swarm this is of course an approximation, but for GR purposes it is good enough. Fitting Kerr solutions to each other is no fun.

Comment: My point is that there would need to be (constant latitude) trajectories that are _not_ orbits; they would need to be sustained by "forces".  Unless I misunderstood your arguments, the "cancelling" orbits you suggest would each have to cross the equator twice per orbit.  So not really any sort of Dyson Sphere that would be interesting in a SF sense.  Or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1):

The WP describes many different concepts that could be called Dyson spheres. However, in all of these concepts the matter is either not moving or moving at nonrelativistic speeds. Therefore you don't need general relativity, and the field is what you would expect from Newtonian physics. The metric is, to this approximation, the Schwarzschild metric (as required by Birkhoff's theorem). The interior and exterior metrics correspond to different masses.